# how to access a Java SDK with C++

Tags: c++, sdk

I'm currently working on a project that must be written in C++, as the other part of the project is in C++. However, I've got to use the U-Prove SDK to accomplish my task. MS provides two kinds of SDK, Java and C#. I'm wondering if there's any way to access the SDK with the C++ code.
So finally what I want is a C++ program, (not two separate program) that can make use of the U-Prove SDK.

BTW, my English sucks, so if there's anything I failed to make clear, feel free to tell me. Thanks.

Comment: So you (a) "have to" use C++, and (b) "have to" use a non-C++ library? Are you sure the requirements didn't get mangled somewhere along the way? Sounds like a design failure.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It could be that the project requires some specific component which requires C/C++. OpenMP comes to mind. At least he isn't trying to mash FORTRAN and Java together :).

Comment: The "standard" (ie, non-Microsoft) way to get from C++ to Java is with the Java JNI interface.  No telling what Microsoft has invented.

Comment: @LiamM thanks and love your humour XD

Answer (score 2):

I'm certainly no authority in this respect, but I have used the JNI (Java Native Interface) to great effect in the past. From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface):

> The Java Native Interface (JNI) is a programming framework that
>   enables Java code running       in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to
>   call and to be called[1] by native applications (programs specific to
>   a hardware and operating system platform) and libraries written in
>   other languages     such as C, C++ and assembly.

I recommend both [this tutorial](http://electrofriends.com/articles/jni/jni-part1-java-native-interface/) and [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jni/index.html) best practices guide. [Here is a free book courtesy of Oracle](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/), however it's quite a bit older than the other material.

I suggest you explore JNI as a solution to a larger set of problems, identify where your problems fit in terms of what JNI can do, and then focus in on these areas.

Answer (score 1):

are you going to use Native C++ or Managed CLR C++?
If it's for .NET / windows app. You can use IKVM. It could compile java code (source code or compiled byte code) into .net  MSIL library, then u can use it in you C++ managed app

Please check out http://ikvm.net

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using native C++, I guess I'll try JNI first. :)